# Using nested objects in redux initial state and reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have dashboard that have a sections which is separated by react-router.

Sections are:

- **Categories**
- **Exams**
- **Reports**

Lets take a look at Exam section. we have this state as the initial state.

```
{
        ID: null,          
        RandomizeQuestions: false,
        RandomizeAnswers: false,
        Pages: [
            {
                ID: 1,
                Title: 'Page one',                
                Blocks: [
                    {
                        ID: 1,
                        Title: 'Block One',                           
                        Questions: [
                            {
                                ID: 1,                                   
                                Title: "Quesiton title is here",
                                Answers: [
                                    {
                                        ID: 1,
                                        Title: "Answer 1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ID: 2,
                                        Title: "Answer 2"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I know that the state should be flatten and normalized when I use redux. but that is my exact problem. if i try to normalize my state it should be like this :

```
{
Exam: {
    ID: null,       
    RandomizeQuestions: false,
    RandomizeAnswers: false
},
ExamPages: [
    {
        ExamId: 1,
        ID: 1,
        Title: 'Page One'           
    }
],
ExamBlocks: [
    {
        ID: 1,
        Title: 'The New Block',            
        Questions: []
    }
],
ExamQuestions: [],
ExamAnswers: []
}
```

lets assume that its ok and I wont have problem with it. but when happen to the other sections ?

**Categories** have its own states which is big too and report too. ( there are other section that I didn't mention )

and then my combineReducer would be looks like this :

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import Exam from './redc.exams.jsx'
import ExamBlocks from './redc.blocks.jsx'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    Exam,
    ExamBlocks
})

export default rootReducer
```

and of course I should have a reducer for every array in that object.

so my main question is how can I at lest have this structure:

```
const initialState = {
    Exams: {
        Blocks: [],
        Questions: [],
        Answers: []
    },
    Categories: {
        Menus: [],
        Users: []
    },
    Report: {
        MainReports: [],
        SideReports: []
    }
}
```

remember that I want to have separate reducers for each of them.
a reducer for Blocks , reducer for Questions and so on...

## UPDATE #1

I tried @Tom Fenech said in the answers but cannot combine reducers before final combineReducers.
right now my root reducers is looks like this:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

//Exams
import Exams from './ExamsReducers/redc.exams.jsx'
import Blocks from './ExamsReducers/redc.blocks.jsx'

//Categories
import Categories from './CategoriesReducers/redc.categories.jsx'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        Exams,
        Categories,
        Blocks,
})

export default rootReducer
```

I tried with what he says and here is my code after the changes:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

//Exams
import Exams from './ExamsReducers/redc.exams.jsx'
import Blocks from './ExamsReducers/redc.blocks.jsx'

//Categories
import Categories from './CategoriesReducers/redc.categories.jsx'

const examRedc = combineReducers(Exams,Blocks )
const catsRedc = combineReducers(Categories)

const rootReducer = combineReducers(examRedc, catsRedc)

export default rootReducer
```

i get this error :

```
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.
```

and when i log the state in one of the components like this

```
var mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
    return {
        AddBlock: function () {
            dispatch(addBlock());
        }
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
    console.log(state); //////HERE
    return {Blocks: state.Blocks};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Blocks)
```

I get this state which is not what I want finally.

[image: final output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to have `Blocks`, `Questions` and `Answers` inside of `Exams`. I would suggest something like this at the top level:

```
{
    Exams: {
        [ID]: {
            ID: string,
            RandomizeQuestions: boolean,
            RandomizeAnswers: boolean,
            Blocks: string[] // array of block IDs
        }
    }
    Blocks: {
        [ID]: {
            ID: string, 
            Title: string,  
            Questions: string[] // array of question IDs
        }
    },
    Questions: // etc.
}
```

Now, instead of storing the nested objects, we just store their ID to keep track of ownership.

This state would be created with:

```
state = combineReducers({
    examsReducer, 
    blocksReducer,
    // ...more reducers
})
```

If you want to split the overall state into sections, you could use something like this:

```
const examStuff = combineReducers({
    examsReducer,
    blocksReducer,
    // ...
});

const categoryStuff = combineReducers({
    categoriesReducer,
    menusReducer,
    // ...
});

const state = combineReducers({
    examStuff,
    categoryStuff
});
```

Then state would be:

```
{
    examStuff: {} // the object defined at the top of question,
    categoryStuff: {},
    otherStuff: {}
}
```

Comment: is it ok if i want to have something like this ?  `Blocks: [
        {
             ID: string, 
             ExamId: string,
            Title: string,  
        }
   ]`

instead of storing those values in the parent

Comment: You should do whatever makes more sense in your application. If it is more useful to be able to easily look up exams for a given block, then it makes sense to store the IDs the other way round. By the way I would use an object rather than an array to make it easier to look up blocks by ID.

Comment: i tried that already. please try this by yourself and you'll see the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can have nested reducer structure like

```
// block_reducer.js
export const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
   case BLOCK_ACTION:
     return [{a:1}, {b:2}]
 }
  return state
}


// exam_reducer.js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {reducer as BlockReducer} from './block_reducer'

export const reducer = combineReducers({
    Blocks: BlockReducer,
    Sections: .....,
    Answers: .......
})

// root_reducer.js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {reducer as examReducers} from './exam_reducers'

export const reducer = combineReducers({
    Exams: examReducers,
    Categories: .....,
    Report: ......
})
```